# TextBox should accept only two numbers after decimal point

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have created a textbox with id of 'txtDFI' in asp.net.And limited it to accept only float values by using below function

```
document.getElementById('txtDFI').onkeydown = function() { return(integerAndFloatOnly()) };
```

My problem is that it should accept only two numbers after decimal point..If user entered 3rd number it shuould not accept..
Can anybody help me how can I meet this requirement in javascript...

ManyThanks..

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967558/only-allow-two-digits-after-decimal-in-textbox

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow only 2 decimal points entry to a textbox using javascript or jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666415/allow-only-2-decimal-points-entry-to-a-textbox-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You could have done some research and have easily found out the answer.

Anyways, here you go:-

1. **Assuming that you need to do something with Class name**

```js
$('.number').keypress(function(event) {
  if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
    ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) &&
      (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8))) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  var text = $(this).val();
  if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) &&
    (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2) &&
    (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
  CSS part

.number {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="number" />
```

[For Complete reference see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796827/jquery-allow-only-two-numbers-after-decimal-point)