# Javascript regex two decimal place expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Can someone explain to me what the following regex is doing in javascript?  I know it only allows for two decimal places but I'm very confused on the multiple "\d" and "." and "\^d." expressions.

Regex expression:
this.value = this.value.replace (/(.\d\d)\d+|([\d.]*)[^\d.]/, '$1$2');

Original StackOverflow question here:
[Allow only 2 decimal points entry to a textbox using javascript or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666415/allow-only-2-decimal-points-entry-to-a-textbox-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: This regex makes no sence. Where did you get it?

Comment: regex101.com explains regex expressions. Here is a link to an explanation of your regex (look at the right side of the screen): https://regex101.com/r/GLtNXX/1

Comment: The $1 and $2 it's the contents of the 2 capture groups of the expression 1st: (.\d\d) 2nd: ([\d.]*). As you're using | it can capture one or the other, which are then mounted in the replace string.